# Edit page for taxonomy tag terms results

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, 7

I have it set up so that when you click a title of a certain part of a page, it directs to another page where anything tagged with that certain tag is included in a list form. However, there are 8 different categories that all fall under this overall category. So, whether you click term A or B or C or whatever, it all links to the same /types/% page, making it impossible for me to customize each one individually (as far as I can tell).

Any tips on how to make each term results page different?